# Rails simple ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

So I started to learn ajax on ruby on rails and very ashame to ask some error, but this error very annoying me, I don't get it, it's because my OS (windows 10) or my code

So I have 5 files, actually I just edit the code after generate from scaffold

The error always error internal server (500), but I couldn't solved it for 2 days, and the data still inserted to database but the div#data-list wont refresh

Here's the code :

1. my index.html.erb :

   ## Listing ajaxxxes

   ```
   <table>
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Title</th>
         <th>Description</th>
         <th colspan="3"></th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <div id="data-list">
       <%= render 'data' %>
     </div>
   </table>

   <br>


   <%= render 'form' %>

   <%= link_to 'New Ajaxxx', new_ajaxxx_path %>
   ```
2. my _data.html.erb :

   ```
   <tbody>
     <% @ajaxxxes.each do |ajaxxx| %>
         <tr>
           <td><%= ajaxxx.title %></td>
           <td><%= ajaxxx.description %></td>
           <td><%= link_to 'Show', ajaxxx %></td>
           <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_ajaxxx_path(ajaxxx) %></td>
           <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', ajaxxx, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
         </tr>
       <% end %>
     </tbody>
   ```
3. my _form.html.erb:

   ```
   <%= form_for(@ajaxxx, remote: true) do |f| %>
     <% if @ajaxxx.errors.any? %>
       <div id="error_explanation">
         <h2><%= pluralize(@ajaxxx.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this ajaxxx from being saved:</h2>

         <ul>
         <% @ajaxxx.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
           <li><%= message %></li>
         <% end %>
         </ul>
       </div>
     <% end %>

     <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :title %><br>
       <%= f.text_field :title %>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :description %><br>
       <%= f.text_area :description %>
     </div>
     <div class="actions">
       <%= f.submit %>
     </div>
   <% end %>
   ```
4. my ajaxxxes_controller :

   ```
   class AjaxxxesController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_ajaxxx, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

     # GET /ajaxxxes
     # GET /ajaxxxes.json
     def index
       @ajaxxxes = Ajaxxx.all
       @ajaxxx = Ajaxxx.new
     end

     # GET /ajaxxxes/new
     def new
       @ajaxxx = Ajaxxx.new
     end

     # POST /ajaxxxes
     # POST /ajaxxxes.json
     def create
       @ajaxxx = Ajaxxx.new(ajaxxx_params)

       respond_to do |format|
         if @ajaxxx.save
           format.html { redirect_to action: "index", notice: 'Ajaxxx was successfully created.' }
           format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @ajaxxx }
           format.js
         else
           format.html { render :new }
           format.json { render json: @ajaxxx.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
         end
       end
     end


     private
       # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
       def set_ajaxxx
         @ajaxxx = Ajaxxx.find(params[:id])
       end

       # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
       def ajaxxx_params
         params.require(:ajaxxx).permit(:title, :description)
       end
   end
   ```
5. and lastly my create.js.erb :

   ```
   <% if @ajaxxx.title %>
               console.log("Ajaxxx created!");
               $("#data-list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'data') %>");
            <% else %>
               console.log("Failed");
            <% end %>
   ```

And here's the log:

```
    Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-01 17:06:01 +0700
      [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
    Processing by AjaxxxesController#index as HTML
      [1m[35mAjaxxx Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "ajaxxxes".* FROM "ajaxxxes"
      Rendered ajaxxxes/_data.html.erb (24.0ms)
      Rendered ajaxxxes/_form.html.erb (60.0ms)
      Rendered ajaxxxes/index.html.erb within layouts/application (160.0ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 468ms (Views: 438.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


    Started GET "/assets/searches.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-01 17:06:02 +0700


    Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-01 17:06:02 +0700


    Started GET "/assets/ajaxxxes.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-01 17:06:02 +0700


    Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-01 17:06:02 +0700


    Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-01 17:06:02 +0700


    Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-01 17:06:02 +0700


    Started GET "/assets/indices.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-01 17:06:02 +0700


    Started GET "/assets/items.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-01 17:06:02 +0700


    Started GET "/assets/searches.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-01 17:06:02 +0700


    Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-01 17:06:02 +0700


    Started POST "/ajaxxxes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-01 17:06:19 +0700
    Processing by AjaxxxesController#create as JS
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "ajaxxx"=>{"title"=>"Test-51", "description"=>"Test-51"}, "commit"=>"Create Ajaxxx"}
      [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
      [1m[35mSQL (0.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "ajaxxxes" ("created_at", "description", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-11-01 10:06:19.915267"], ["description", "Test-51"], ["title", "Test-51"], ["updated_at", "2015-11-01 10:06:19.915267"]]
      [1m[36m (15.6ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
      Rendered ajaxxxes/_data.html.erb (62.5ms)
      Rendered ajaxxxes/create.js.erb (109.4ms)
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 344ms

    ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
        1: <tbody>
        2:     <% @ajaxxxes.each do |ajaxxx| %>
        3:       <tr>
        4:         <td><%= ajaxxx.title %></td>
        5:         <td><%= ajaxxx.description %></td>
      app/views/ajaxxxes/_data.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_ajaxxxes__data_html_erb___834628740_45308136'
      app/views/ajaxxxes/create.js.erb:3:in `_app_views_ajaxxxes_create_js_erb___336360114_45416052'
      app/controllers/ajaxxxes_controller.rb:30:in `create'


      Rendered C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.0ms)
      Rendered C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (0.0ms)
      Rendered C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.text.erb (665.1ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the error:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
        1: <tbody>
        2:     <% @ajaxxxes.each do |ajaxxx| %>
```

The problem is your `@ajaxxxes` variable is not defined.

---

This error appears at `app/controllers/ajaxxxes_controller.rb:30:in create` (the `format.js` line, which invokes `/app/views/ajaxxxes/create.js.erb`:

```
<% if @ajaxxx.title %>
   console.log("Ajaxxx created!");
   $("#data-list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'data') %>");
<% else %>
   console.log("Failed");
<% end %>
```

---

The issue here is: `<%= escape_javascript(render 'data') %>`

`app/views/ajaxxxes/_data.html.erb` contains reference to `@ajaxxxes`:

```
<tbody>
  <% @ajaxxxes.each do |ajaxxx| %>
```

[Rails partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) are designed to be called from any part of your application. Thus you should *never* reference `@instance` variables inside them (the variable might not be available, as it isn't in this case).

Thus, the fix for your error is *either* to use a ["local" variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables), or to omit the call to `data` from your `create.js.erb`:

```
#app/views/ajaxxxes/create.js.erb
<% if @ajaxxx.title %>
   console.log("Ajaxxx created!");
   $("#data-list").html("<%=j render 'data', locals: {ajaxxxes: @ajaxxxes} %>");
<% else %>
   console.log("Failed");
<% end %>

#app/controllers/ajaxxxes_controller.rb
class AjaxxxesController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @ajaxxxes = Ajaxxx.all
      ...
   end
end

#app/views/ajaxxxes/_data.html.erb
<tbody>
  <% ajaxxxes.each do |ajaxxx| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= ajaxxx.title %></td>
        <td><%= ajaxxx.description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', ajaxxx %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_ajaxxx_path(ajaxxx) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', ajaxxx, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <tbody>
    2:     <% @ajaxxxes.each do |ajaxxx| %>
```

That means that the `@ajaxxxes` variable is `nil` and not an array. Please check in your corresponding controller method for a missing assignment to `@ajaxxxes` (or perhaps there is a typo).

Answer (score 1):

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for
>   nil:NilClass)

The problem is here in this line

```
<% @ajaxxxes.each do |ajaxxx| %>
```

Since the code belongs to a ***partial***, you should pass instance variable(`@ajaxxxes`) as a local variable while rendering the partial

The below changes should work

```
<%= render 'data', ajaxxxes: @ajaxxxes %>
```

And change

```
<% @ajaxxxes.each do |ajaxxx| %>
```

to

```
<% ajaxxxes.each do |ajaxxx| %>
```